# OS X Terminal: 'ls' shows program but then says command not found?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, terminal, command-line

I am trying to start MongoDB from the terminal. When I navigate to the folder and hit 'ls', all the applications show up but when I type in the name of the application( 'mongod'), it says it is not found!

```
Abes-MacBook-Air:bin abe$ ls

bsondump    mongodump   mongoimport mongorestore    mongostat
mongo       mongoexport mongooplog  mongos      mongotop
mongod      mongofiles  mongoperf   mongosniff

Abes-MacBook-Air:bin abe$ mongod

-bash: mongod: command not found
```

What is going on?

Answer (score 5):

The executable is in your current working directory. Therefore you need to add `./` to your command. So try `./mongod`.

See this UNIX StackExchange question for details and background:
[Why do we use “./” to execute a file?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4430/why-do-we-use-to-execute-a-file)